# Why can't I override "OnValidate()" in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm implementing a curved Text class that inherits from Text. In it I have this OnValidate implementation:

```
protected override  void OnValidate()
{
  base.OnValidate();
  // some other code
}
```

Now when I try to build the project I get this error :

```
error CS0115: CurvedText.OnValidate() is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override
```

So then I was ok this is wierd even VS suggest the overriding. So what do I do next? Remove the override keyword and ignore the VS warning. So now unity throws this error :

```
error CS0117: UnityEngine.UI.Text does not contain a definition for OnValidate
```

So what do I do now ? I should also mention that when the script is added to a object in the scene it works just as expected and no errors are being thrown.

Comment: There is no OnValidate in base class for override

Comment: but the thing is there is. [Check this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html)

Comment: According to the reference, `OnValidate` is not `virtual`, so it cannot be overriden. This might just be an inaccuracy of the script reference, but since VS agrees, it's probably true.

Comment: "protected void OnValidate();" not virtual

Comment: I'd note that Unity3D was designed JavaScript first, so it doesn't necessarily follow good C# practices. This includes the way inheritance is handled. `OnValidate` and friends are considered messages, not methods, and they are not `virtual` - instead, AFAIK, Unity handles the virtual dispatch manually.

Comment: anyways OnValidate is supposed to be only called in the Editor. Why is trying to build it  and how do I get around that ? Also OnValidate is already overridden in the base implementation of Text so I should be able to override it too.

Comment: Very weird. I started having this issue with third-party plugins and even official packages (TextMeshPro!), but only with Unity 2018.3.12f1 on Linux. Logically, the code shouldn't have compiled from the beginning! Somewhat there was a virtual method named OnValidate defined somewhere in Unity ~2018, and at some point between 2018.3.7f and 2018.3.12f1 they decided to clean it up? Anyway, it's back to "normal" now, so the question and answer should both be valid with the last version. Third-party (and Unity packages!) using override should now update their code.

Comment: OK, it seems that after a restart (maybe cleaning Cache), OnValidate is virtual again and not using override will spawn a warning that you're hiding the method, and should either use new or override... So reverting to override for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `OnValidate` is part of the Unity3D Messaging System.

And as [this blog](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/) mentions this messaging function will only resolved when
 a MonoBehaviour Object first time is accessed and the underlying script is inspected through scripting runtime (either Mono or IL2CPP).

So right now, for the compilier, ther is no `OnValidate` to override.

Simply call the method like this:

```
void OnValidate()
{
   // some other code
}
```

---

*My 2 Cents to the comments*

- The `protected` Keyword doesn't prevent things from being overwritten.
- The `virtual` Keyword is used to modify things and allowing them to be overridden in a derived class. This means you cannot override a non-virtual method.

Comment: Ok this works both in the build and the editor but now VS is complaining that I hide the inherited member. I guess I can live with a single green line in there. Thanks man/

Comment: I stumbled yesterday about this blog entry. No problem!

Comment: _"doesn't mean it's wrong."_ sounds like total butchery of the C# language specification to me.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to override `OnValidate()` if you explicitly make it editor only by using a preprocessor directive.

Unity documentation for `OnValidate()` states "*Called in the editor only*":
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html

So, you can prevent both the VS complaint and the compiler error by using a preprocessor directive `#if UNITY_EDITOR` when overriding `OnValidate()`. This is also more explicit about what the code does instead of relying on insight on Unity internals, hence more readable.

It is probably hidden from builds behind the scenes as an editor-only code, but that hack is broken somehow when it is overridden.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    protected override void OnValidate()
    {
        // Do something.
    }
#endif // UNITY_EDITOR
```